# Clever desktop links options?

Tags: linux-mint, desktop-environment, browser

I want to replicate something I had in Windows land. I would like to populate my desktop so it's like a "panel" of shortcuts or links to commonly used directories and URLs. I have a bunch of websites and I really want to be able to reduce the amount of mouse gymnastics I'm presently doing when navigating to start a session.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using? The DE would determine the process.

Comment: Hi Vaughan, thanks for answering! I'm using Cinnamon.

Comment: The file manager can have directory shortcuts in the sidebar, IIRC. Web browser can be set up to keep the browser tabs from the last session on startup (firefox). Those do the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

From chromium, I can simply drag a URL from the browser address bar to the desktop.

As for directories, open your file browser, right click on the directory you want to link to and select "Make link". Then, drag the newly created link to the desktop.

Comment: Turns out the "make link" isn't in the right-click menu for Nemo - but it is in the Edit menu, or ctrl+M. Thanks!

Comment: @Johnwilldo you're welcome :) If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.